# ¿Cuándo un pronombre interrogativo puede aparecer fuera de su oración?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis, pronombre-interrogativo

En el libro *Claves del lenguaje humano* se afirma que la oración "¿Qué dijo Pedro que Berta había comprado?" (formada a partir de "Pedro dijo que Berta había comprado un coche.") es correcta.

Sin embargo, se afirma que es agramatical preguntar "*¿Qué preguntó Pedro si Berta había comprado?" a partir de la oración "Pedro preguntó si Berta había comprado un coche". La única explicación que se ofrece al respecto es que "las palabras interrogativas como *qué* [...] pueden aparecer fuera de su oración aunque no en todos los casos".

¿En qué casos **no** puede aparecer un pronombre interrogativo fuera de su oración y por qué?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las preguntas con pronombre interrogativo solo pueden contener proposiciones nominales introducidas por "que". Normalmente, el pronombre interrogativo siempre se referirá al verbo dentro de la proposición:

- ¿Qué dijo Pedro **que** Berta había comprado? / Un reloj.
- ¿Dónde dijo Pedro **que** Berta había comprado un reloj? / Lo compró en una tienda.
- ¿Cuándo dijo Pedro **que** Berta había comprado un reloj? / Lo compró ayer.
- ¿Por qué dijo Pedro **que** Berta había comprado un reloj? / Lo compró porque perdió el que tenía.

Esto tiene sentido porque, en afirmativo, aparece la conjunción "que" del lenguaje indirecto:

- Pedro dijo **que** Berta compró un reloj en una tienda ayer porque perdió el que tenía.

Answer (score 0):

A mi parece que toda la oración:  "¿Qué preguntó Pedro si Berta había comprado?" es incorrecta en cuanto a la gramática por causa de la palabra "si".  Tampoco parece que se podría preguntar así con la pregunta sóla, sin la oración afirmativa.  Lo que pasa es que no queda clara la pregunta:  ¿Está preguntando Pedro sólo si Berta había comprado algo? ¿o es que Pedro pregunta por si Berta haya comprado?

Creo que si uno piensa en el significado, y en lo que está diciendo en la oración completa, puede ser más fácil discernir de entre lo correcto y lo incorrecto en cuanto a la gramática de la pregunta.